# How to store static (common data) in databases

Tags: sql, database, database-design, schema, database-schema

Imagine, I want to record marks scored by participants in exam, and for every record total marks will remain same. So I will want to store just obtained marks, and this common data (static in terms of C# language) should be not be stored redundantly against each record, as its same for all records. I understand its not exactly redundancy by definition of normalization as it is a legitimate data for each record. But again there should be some better and smart mean to store such static/common/metadata information.

I know one argument will be to incorporate such business logic thing either in middle tier or better in logical schema of db (by virtue of views). But again we want each and every data to lie in tables, and logical data just be induced from data available in tables, rather it hold its alien data/info.

Can anyone suggest better?

Comment: Could you give a [mcve] of this common data and your current schema for it?

Comment: Better you can store MAXIMUM MARKS with a subject table called maximum_marks, so, there will be only one value for one subject and while calculating % you can get join the MARKS OBTAIN table with SUBJECT.

Comment: @Filburt : I mentioned the example in original post, marks obtained is data specified to record, but total marks for that table will remain constant/common, so how to store that static data

Comment: @Vivek : Yet have to record fk against each obtained marks, so technically equivalent to store maximum marks against the record.

Comment: @Cellman It's really not clear how *total marks* is a "static value for this table". Commonly *total marks* suggests an aggregate, not a static value. I can only suspect that it is actually not the number of marks, but the number of exams you consider static. Again, a valid answer should be based on a schema, not just a vague description.

Comment: @filburt: the maximum marks is common data between all the records in the particular table.

Comment: @Cellman Maximum marks obtainable is a fact about the exam, not the about the result of an individual student.

Answer (score 0):

You need a table for the exam, which would include the maximum marks value, the name of the exam
And a separate table for the exam_results. Likely this is a many to many relationship between exam and student.
To push the point, you might also want a venues table, which might have a maximum number of students who can take an exam, then an exam_sessions table as a many to many relationship between exam and venue.